# How to load databricks package dbutils in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I was trying to run the below code in pyspark.

```
dbutils.widgets.text('config', '', 'config')
```

It was throwing me an error saying

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined
```

so, Is there any way I can run it in pyspark by including the databricks package ,like an import ?

Your help is appreciated

Comment: In a package/module I have `from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils` and `def get_secerts(dbutils: DBUtils):` Then you can use `dbutils.secrets.get()` as you would in a notebook.

Answer (score 16):

As of databricks runtime v3.0 the answer provided by **pprasad009** above no longer works.
Now use the following:

```
def get_dbutils(spark):

      dbutils = None
      
      if spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.client.enabled") == "true":
        
        from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
        dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
      
      else:
        
        import IPython
        dbutils = IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
      
      return dbutils

dbutils = get_dbutils(spark)
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect#access-dbutils

Comment: before doing the above, I could not do `import dbutils`, but this worked: `dbutils.library.restartPython()`. After running the above, restartPython does not work with error message that dbutils has no attrib library. Any help?

Answer (score 11):

as explained in 
https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dev-tools/db-connect.html#access-dbutils

depending on where you are executing your code directly on databricks server (eg. using databricks notebook to invoke your project egg file) or from your IDE using databricks-connect you should initialize dbutils as below. (where spark is your SparkSession)

```
def get_dbutils(spark):
    try:
        from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
        dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
    except ImportError:
        import IPython
        dbutils = IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
    return dbutils

dbutils = get_dbutils(spark)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the sources of `dbutils.py` (from `databricks-connect==11.3.11`
) it is no longer necessary to check

```
if spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.client.enabled") == "true":
   ...
```

This is done in the `class DBUtils`.  So the code below will do the same as stated in the other answers:

```py
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
```

You can also see there that the remote solution (`spark.databricks.service.client.enabled==true`) of `dbutils` only supports `fs` and `secrets`.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala you can

```
import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils
```

And follow below links for more dependency..

https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/dbutils.html

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming that you want the code to be run on databricks cluster. 
If so, then there is no need to import any package as Databricks by default includes all the necessary libraries for dbutils.

I tried using it on databricks (python/scala) notebook without importing any libraries and it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Yes Ritesh,but I dont have databricks cluster . So ,just finding an alternative to import packages.

Comment: As per my knowledge, you have to run your code on databricks cluster if you wish to use dbutils. Please let me know if you find any alternative.